# No matter what i do, the product name is displayed in the console inspector as Product "Name: undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to fetch the name of the product using it's api based on the productId. No matter what i did i can't seem to make it happen. It shows as blank in the html page, and even the call in the console inspector is like this Product "Name: undefined".
I can fetch the productId and it's shown in the console , just the 'Name' isn't being fetched

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Product } from '../product.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-image',
  templateUrl: './product-image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-image.component.scss']
})
export class ProductImageComponent implements OnInit {
  productId!: number;
  productName: string = '';
  apiUrl = 'The api link works very well';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Retrieve the product ID from the route parameters as a string
    const productIdParam = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (productIdParam !== null) {
      this.productId = parseInt(productIdParam, 10);
    }

    // Fetch the product by ID to get the product name
    this.fetchProduct(this.productId);
  }

  getProduct(productId: number): Observable<Product> {
    console.log('Fetching product with ID:', productId);
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${productId}`;
    return this.http.get<Product>(url);
  }

  fetchProduct(productId: number): void {
    this.getProduct(productId).subscribe(
      (product: Product) => {
        this.productName = product.Name;
        console.log('Product ID:', this.productId);
        console.log('Product Name:', this.productName);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching product:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I tried everything but I kept having "Name: undefined", this is my product model.ts

```
export class Product {
    ProductId: number = 0;
    Name: string = '';
    Description: string = '';
    Price: number = 0;
    Availability: boolean = false;
    CategoryId: number = 0;
    BrandId: number = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your backend is probably not returning what you are expecting. Check it with `console.log(product)`

Comment: Adding that returns all the data of that 'productId' as expected. Just this " console.log('Product Name:', this.productName);" is the one that's not working as expected.

Comment: We can’t help if you don’t show the actual response. My guess is - ot returns something different then you expect

Comment: This is the result i'm getting https://snipboard.io/bfrwi4.jpg

Comment: So, it is just `name`, not `Name`

Comment: No, i don't think so.. This is my product model https://snipboard.io/zuxmvT.jpg

Comment: Your model doesn't match the backend result. Typing only exist at compile time, it will never validate at runtime.